# Are common IR LEDs harmful to the eyes?

Tags: led, infrared, energy

Is it safe to look at the IR LED clusters on security cameras that are commonly available? They seem to be quite capable of lighting up a distance of 6m. What is their energy density? I'm not sure if it'd be reasonable to assume 150mW/sr. A cluster of 12 such LEDs would mean 1.8W/sr.

Comment: My one LED 1 battery torchlight is quite capable of lighting up a distance of 6m too. The biggest danger from it is poking  out an eye with it.

Comment: Would you also be worried about a 50 W light bulb ? As far as I know these emit **a lot more** IR than a small IR LED. Remember that any warm object emits IR.

Comment: 10 milliWatt/centimeter^2 is one limit for visible Laser energy into the eye.

Comment: Yes, but lasers are a very different proposition!

Comment: Infrared-no. You would need a lot of "heat" to cook an eye. Ultra-Violet on the other hand.... don't forget to wear the cooky glasses..

Comment: @Trevor But our receptors react to infrared differently. They don't 'shut' as they would when they sense visible light.

Comment: I don't have infra-red receptors in my eyes. But he point is your eyes can be exposed to much higher infra-red from other sources.  Here is a paper on it though http://www.intersil.com/content/dam/Intersil/documents/an17/an1737.pdf They even have a calculator that tells you if you are over. At least by their definitions.